# IOS TableView scroll only some rows

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have a UITableView with 122 elements and I can only scroll some of the rows.
I got the ContentSize height into a variable and the height of the table seems to be ok.

That`s how I implemented the UITableView:

```
_tableView = new UITableView
            {
                BackgroundColor = AppColors.Clear.ToNativeColor(),
                SeparatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero,
                TableFooterView = new UIView(CGRect.Empty),
                ScrollEnabled = true,
                EstimatedRowHeight = 50,
                RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension,
            };
```

I have the following constraints:

```
 View.AddConstraints(
 _tableView.Below(_header),
                _tableView.AtLeftOf(View),
                _tableView.AtRightOf(View),
                _tableView.WithSameWidth(View));
```

In ViewWillAppear I set the height of the tableView like this:

```
 var tableHeight = _tableView.ContentSize.Height;
 View.AddConstraints(_tableView.Height().EqualTo(tableHeight));
```

So, I cannot scroll to the bottom of the table, only I can scroll on maximum 20 elements.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: is your table view frame is same as screen? why your tableview height is fixed?

Comment: Are you using these two functions?
...
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  return 1
 }
    ...
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return yourData.count ?? 0
    }

Comment: If I don`t set a height for the tableView, it doesn`t show anything on the screen. I checked the frame size and it has the same height as the TableView.

Comment: Your tableView height should not be constant, add top and bottom constraint to the tableView, so it will automatically set tableView height.

Comment: The height of the tableView is calculated according to the elements from source

Comment: Height of tableView won't affect the scroll in a tableview. Even if you set a height 10   to a tableView, you can see all the elements in the tableView by scrolling down. Why is `only I can scroll on maximum 20 elements` here? Did you ever scrolled? Share more code about the dataSource and tableView please.